# Embed script only on production with Vue CLI 3

Tags: vue.js, webpack-4

My main goal is to inject a  tag into my index.html only in production (it's a New Relic monitoring code snippet).

My Vue.js is built and served as a static resource, so using {% %} tags to surround the script block with a condition doesn't seem to work in this use case.

So I tried to add the New Relic code snippet on my Vue.js app using html-webpack-plugin, since I found a simple Webpack plugin using on html-webpack-plugin. It's a pretty simple plugin, it just create the  node and pushes it in the page body : https://github.com/robrap/html-webpack-new-relic-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js#L25

I register the plugin by setting my `vue.config.js` this way (I first tried to add the script no matter the environment) :

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackNewRelicPlugin = require('@yodatech/html-webpack-new-relic-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackNewRelicPlugin({the plugin options})
    ]
  }
}
```

The plugin actually does its job well (the code snippet is injected), but its execution messes up with Vue CLI default configuration.

Some stylesheets and scripts aren't referenced anymore in the final index.html file, the `<div id=app></div>` is not there anymore, the app is broken.

I don't know if using HtmlWebpackPlugin is a dead end, but I currently don't know any other way to reach my goal.

Has anyone an idea on how I could make this work ?

Thanks a lot to anyone passing by.

EDIT : The plugin I was trying to use seemed to be flawed, I had to modify it to make it work with Vue CLI. My main problem has been solved by the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vue.config.js` option `configureWebpack` just [merges the options](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) you provide to a webpack config provided by Vue CLI. So by using your code, you are running 2 distinct `HtmlWebpackPlugin`s (one from your config and one default from Vue CLI)

Try this instead:

```js
var HtmlWebpackNewRelicPlugin = require('@yodatech/html-webpack-new-relic-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackNewRelicPlugin({the plugin options})
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I checked the piece of documentation you linked, I was not aware of it and your suggestion makes total sense according to it. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Two things : if I remove the "html-webpack-plugin" from my package.json the plugin isn't executed at all. If I keep it, it is executed, but the 'alterAssetTagGroups' tap at https://github.com/robrap/html-webpack-new-relic-plugin/blob/10ba3cf274f25a788b849371a3f321923e434fe6/src/index.js#L27 is never triggered (it is correctly added though). Maybe this plugin isn't the way to go.

Comment: I didn't tell you to remove `html-webpack-plugin` from `package.json`. That plugin is used by Vue CLI - you can check the Webppack config used by Vue CLI by executing `vue inspect` on command line. Just don't add it to `vue.config.js` as Vue CLI includes that plugin by default....

Comment: Removing was just a test, I thought it was weird that my plugin wasn't executed at all when removing it since it is a dev dependency of Vue CLI. Anyway, your answer allowed me to get the plugin executed without messing with Vue CLI settings. I managed to get the plugin working by forking it and modifying it, I found a hook that was actually called during the build. It now works wonderfully. Thanks again !